# Drag and Drop outlook attachment in to Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, outlook, air

I would like to know if there is a way to drag and drop an attachment file from an outlook email that is open into an AIR application and for that file to be then accessible to the AIR application.

When I experimented with this the drag operation is giving AIR a File Promise List.  But I'm not exactly sure how to make use of it once it is dropped.  All the examples out there explain how to manupilate File Promises from an AIR application to the desktop.  Nothing that explains a file promise into an AIR app.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AIR is like any other desktop application in this aspect: you are notified that a thing of type File Promise List is in the clipboard. You have to deal with this type (as any other desktop application would).

If this is the Windows clipboard call-back thing, then AIR's limitations might be a problem. Applications have the option, through the Windows API, to put a token in the clipboard rather than actually moving the data into global memory, which is what the clipboard is. If anyone actually wants the data, the original app gets a callback and supplies the byte stream.

If this is the case, AIR could do whatever the consumer application is supposed to do asynchronously, but I don't know if it does. Or it could be some particular Outlook thing.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to drag and drop an attachment file from an outlook e-mail.

@Richard: AIR doesn't allow dropping message files to an AIR-Application.

Instead you receive a String, containing some mail info like subject, size, recipient.
No content, no attachments.

That's a pity...
Please feel free to correct me, but I have searched for a solution for a while and no solution found....
Greetings steelheart